# Can the Pi run an embedded RTOS other than Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, real-time

I have a hobby project that requires a real-time MCU running an embedded RTOS like [embox](https://github.com/embox/embox) or something comparable.

I know that it is typical for the RPi to be ran with a Linux flavor like Raspian, Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

**Can RPi be hacked/configured to run embox instead?** If so, how (general procedures, links to documentation, etc.)? If not, why?

Comment: What are the real-time requirements for your project?

Comment: Thanks @joan - the requirements are that the OS must guarantee the timing of certain critical events, or safety issues could arise. If I'm correctly reading between the lines of your comment above, it sounds like the answer to this question is *no*!

Comment: I don't know, as I don't know the requirements.  It depends on what the events are, what outputs are triggered by each event, and the time allowed for each transaction.  You may be able to rule out the Pi if you detail the event with the shortest overall transaction time.

Comment: Thanks again @joan but I think you're concentrating on the wrong part of my question. Rather than focusing on what my project requirements are, and whether or not they can be guaranteed by Linux, the main part of the question (which is in **bold** above) is: **Can RPi be hacked/configured to run embox?** So forget what my needs are, or why I might want to do this: I'm simply asking, is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think you understand what really defines a RTOS. We can't answer your entire question if you don't answer @joan's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with embox. But the way I see it you need a version of embox that is built for `armv6l` (the CPU on the RPi1) or for `armv7` (in case of an RPi2). 
Given that such a build is not available, I'd say the answer is NO at this moment.
You might want to check out [this project](https://github.com/embox/embox/issues/705) though.

You might have more luck with [a BeagleBoard](https://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/PlatformBeagleBoardSd)

Comment: It might be worth including that an RPi 2 requires a v7 in an edit. Otherwise +1

Comment: @Jacobm001: Consider it done

Answer (score 0):

**Can Embox be hacked/configured to run on the RPi:**

The answer to this question is: "maybe".  Embox is written for embeddable platforms, and is open source.  Embox can certainly be tweaked and compiled for the RPi.  In fact, there's an open issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/embox/embox/issues/705) to do such a thing. If this is what you want to do, prepare yourself.  This won't be a simple endeavor.